# how to make the keyboard show search icon when searching ? (React-native)

Tags: react-native, textinput

I was wondering is it possible in react-native to when doing a search to search icon at the bottom corner like instagram.

Also is it possible using TextInput native Component
Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add [returnKeyType](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#returnkeytype) as `'search'` for your required keyboard.